# Unable to mole clasess which use new keyword in inherited methods

Tags: moles

I have the following scenario

```
public abstract ClassA{
   public virtual void Initialize(string a, int b){
   }
}

public abstract ClassB : ClassA{
   public virtual int Initialize(string a, int b){
   }
}
```

When I try to create stub for Class B, I receive the error saying that SClassB already defines a member called 'Initialize' with the same parameter types.

How do I resolve the issue?

Thanks,
Sathish

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can not override within an abstract class so you would either need to lose the abstract/virtual and use override modifier on ClassB, or override it in the class(es) that inherits from ClassB.

Comment: I forgot to include one statement in ClassB class. The Initialize method in Class B calls the base class Initialize method. 

    public abstract ClassB : ClassA{
   public virtual int Initialize(string a, int b){
      base.Initialize(a, b);
   }
}

If I use override, I might end up calling the base.Initialize twice. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you calling Initialize from ClassA's constructor? Don't do that. There's even a code analysis rule for that!